# java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner

Tags: android, runtimeexception

```
mSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (id == 2) {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.added_alert));
                    checkBoxAlarm.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    checkBoxAlarm.setEnabled(false);
                    checkBoxAlarm.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (id == 3) {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.notify));
                    checkboxnotify.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    checkboxnotify.setEnabled(false);
                    checkboxnotify.setChecked(false);
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the error: **setOnItemClickListener cannot be used**

Use

```
setOnItemSelectedListener
```

instead of

```
setOnItemClickListener
```

Firstly you should change this. Then you can use **position**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `position` in place of `id` while you want to compare the position of the selected item in the spinner.

```
mSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position == 2) {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.added_alert));
                    checkBoxAlarm.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    checkBoxAlarm.setEnabled(false);
                    checkBoxAlarm.setChecked(false);
                }
                if (position == 3) {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.notify));
                    checkboxnotify.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    checkboxnotify.setEnabled(false);
                    checkboxnotify.setChecked(false);
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OnItemSelectedListener`
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner#SelectListener